# What would cause weird NGINX behaviour which is fixed by a reload?

Tags: nginx

As the title suggests, we've got a weird issue which appears on our web servers.

We have a number of configurations (virtualhosts) on each web box, all of which behave perfectly, except one.

After a period of time (days or weeks) this hosts just starts timing out and returning 502 responses.

Configuration tests return fine, but the only fix is to run `nginx -s reload` when it begins responding correctly again.

**Details**:

nginx 1.10.0

ubuntu 12.04

There are 8 hosts/configs in total which nginx serves.

The config in question in below incase there is something which may flag something up.

```
limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=analytics:100m   rate=10r/s;
proxy_cache_path /var/www/analytics-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=analytics:10m max_size=10g inactive=1d;
proxy_temp_path /var/www/analytics-cache/tmp; 

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name analytics.domain.com;

    location /no-cache {
        proxy_pass https://remote.server.com/path/to/endpoint;
        limit_req   zone=analytics burst=10;
     }

     location / {
         proxy_pass http://analytics.domain.com/no-cache;
         expires                1h;
         proxy_cache            analytics;
         proxy_cache_key        $http_host$request_uri;
         proxy_cache_valid      200 1h;

         proxy_cache_methods    GET;
         proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
                              http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
         proxy_ignore_headers   "X-Accel-Expires";
         proxy_ignore_headers   "Expires";
         proxy_ignore_headers   "Cache-Control";
         add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see in htop when nginx stop respons?

Comment: Nothing unusual

Comment: What does the error log say around this time?